# Help with psychological research for my dissertation?

Tags: anova, sample-size, sample, median

1) Is median split effective to divide participants in 2 groups considering their scores on a scale? I am using PECK scale (Personal experience checlist) and i need to divide participants into minimum and maximum level of bullying.
I have some concern because I found that I have too many ps with min bullying experiences and not enough with maximum bullying experiences. Should I recruit some more?
2) I am using mixed ANOVA and one way ANOVA and i have used opportunity sampling. Can I use Gpower analysis to determine sample size? Do you think 30 participants would be enough?

Answer (score 1):

Dichotomizing a variable this way is almost never a good idea, unless there is strong substantive justification for doing so. Since you are considering median split, you clearly do not have that justification. You should leave the scale as it is. Why do you "need" to do this?

If you are interested in this scale as a dependent variable and are interested in people with high degrees of bullying, I suggest looking into quantile regression.

If you used opportunity sampling then some people would argue that power is irrelevant, since you don't have a random sample. However, if you decide to assume that your sample is a random one from some population (a common assumption in psychology) then Gpower ought to work, but no one can answer whether 30 is enough - that's why we use programs like Gpower.